# Evading the fewer dependent variables than equations error

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages, automation

I'm writing a code that tries to solve differential equations generated from some existing code. The equations so generated are often seemingly overdetermined but actually solvable: e.g.

```
{f'[x] == 0, f''[x] == 0 }
```

However, plugging this into `DSolve` spits the `DSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables than equations, so the system is overdetermined` error.

These equations can of course be preprocessed by hand before feeding into `DSolve`. But I wonder if there is a way to **automatically** solve this kind of equations?

Comment: It's like we need a "`DReduce[]"`...

Comment: As far as ad hoc approaches go, the most straightforward to modify the given system is `DSolve[First@{f'[x] == 0, f''[x] == 0 }, f x]` or simply `DSolve[f'[x] == 0, f, x]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
DSolve[{f'[x] == 0, g'[x] == 0, f'[y] == g[y]}, {f, g}, x]

(*   {{f -> Function[{x}, C[1]], g -> Function[{x}, 0]}}   *)
```

Or

```
fsol = f /. Flatten@DSolve[{f''[x] == 0}, f, x]

(*  Function[{x}, C[1] + x C[2]]    *)

sol = Flatten@Solve[fsol'[x] == 0]

(*   {C[2] -> 0}   *)

f[x_] = fsol[x] /. sol

(*   C[1]   *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a start (a truck fire shutdown the highway and we were stuck in the mountains; so I had some extra time and got the below to work with systems as well). Assumptions about input:

- The systems essentially can be reduced to one equation for each dependent variable.
- The equations are ODEs.

In this case, we may deduce the order of the desired ODE and use `Solve` to find it. I guess I have supposed it is obvious, at least in the examples below, that the output of `dReduce` may be plugged into `DSolve`.

```
dReduce // ClearAll;
iDReduce // ClearAll;

dReduce::incon = 
  "The system of differential equations is inconsistent.";
dReduce::noivar = 
  "No independent variables were specified; specify one.";
dReduce::nopde = 
  "There is more than one independent variable ``: PDEs are not implemented.";
dReduce::nodvar = 
  "No dependent variables were specified; specify one.";

dReduce[sys1_, y1_, x1_] := Module[
   {sys, y, x, dorder, redorder, res, tests = 0},
   sys = Flatten@{sys1};
   x = Flatten@{x1};
   y = Flatten@{y1 /. v_[Sequence @@ x] :> v};
   (* check inputs *)
   Switch[Length@x,
    0, Message[dReduce::noivar],
    1, tests++,
    _, Message[dReduce::nopde, x]];
   Switch[Length@y,
    0, Message[dReduce::nodvar],
    _, tests++];
   (* call the solver *)
   (dorder = 
      Flatten@Internal`ProcessEquations`DifferentialOrder[sys, x, y];
     redorder = Length@y + Total@dorder - Length@sys;
     iDReduce[sys, y, First@x, dorder, redorder]) /; tests == 2
   ];
(* adding systems made this a bit more complicated *)
iDReduce[sys_, y_, x_, dorder_, redorder_] := 
  Module[{orders, res, a},
   With[{vars = Array[a, Length@y]},
    orders = SolveValues[ (* possible target orders *)
      Join[{Total@vars == redorder}, 
       Thread[0 <= Array[a, Length@y] <= dorder]],
      vars, Integers]
    ];
   orders = SortBy[orders, -Min[#] &]; (* heuristic: avoid zero-order *)
   res = Do[ (* try each order - first to succeed wins *)
     res = Solve[
       sys,
       Flatten@MapThread[
         Table[Derivative[n][#1][x], {n, #2, #3, -1}] &,
         {y, dorder, orders[[k]]}
         ]
       ];
     If[MatchQ[res, {{__Rule} ..}],
      Return[{res, orders[[k]]}, Do]],
     {k, Length@orders}];
   With[{dvars = MapThread[Derivative[#1][#2][x] &, {Last@res, y}]},
     Thread[
       Times @@ (Thread[dvars - #] & /@
        (dvars /. First@res)) == 0] // 
      Simplify
     ] /; MatchQ[res, {{{___Rule} ...}, _}]
   ];
```

Examples.

OP's:

```
dReduce[{f'[x] == 0, f''[x] == 0}, f, x]
(*  f'[x] == 0  *)
```

OP's with a twist:

```
dReduce[{f'[x] + f''[x] == f''[x], f''[x] == 0}, f, x]
(*  {f'[x] == 0}  *)
```

With another twist:

```
dReduce[{f'''[x] + f''[x] == f''[x], f''[x] == 0}, f, x]
(*  {f''[x] == 0}  *)
```

Nesting `D[]` is an easy way to create redundant equations:

```
dReduce[NestList[D[#, t] &, y'[t] + y[t]^3 == 0, 3], y, t]
(*  {y[t]^3 + y'[t] == 0}  *)
```

Nonlinear:

```
dReduce[NestList[D[#, t] &, y''[t]^2 + t^2 y[t] == 0, 2], y, t]
(*  {t^2 y[t] + y''[t]^2 == 0}  *)
```

System:

```
dReduce[
 NestList[D[#, t] &, {y'[t] == x[t], x''[t] == -y[t]}, 2],
 {x,y}, t]
(*  {y[t] + x''[t] == 0, x[t] == y'[t]}  *)
```

Comment: TBD: Decide how to handle `ConditionalExpression` solutions returned by `Solve`. `DSolve` doesn't like conditions, so could simply use `res = Normal@Solve[...]` in `iDReduce` and hope for the best.